# How to stop unwanted aura debugs in salesforce?

Tags: developer-console, debugging

I have this developer org, Where I have been spammed with unwanted debug logs which are coming from /Aura operations.

[image]

I am working on classic UI. Mainly on triggers. So I am no way using any /Aura operations. And this issue is also same in some other orgs as well.

Does anyone know how to stop this debugs? Because these does not contain any useful information as well. And due to these many logs (5 Logs per second approx.) developer console works very slow.

I have tried removing all the debug level from the "Change log level..." but it does not help.

If anyone knows the solution it will be much helpful.

Comment: You wouldn't get Aura logs unless you have one or more Aura components running. Do you share your username with anyone? Is there anyone else in your org?

Comment: @sfdcfox sorry for the late update, but no. I do not share the username with anyone. It's just me using it.